# How do I create a criteria where the parameter is a member of a collection field on the table?

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I have a class that has the following structure:

```
public class Machine {
    private Set<Line> lines;
}
```

Now what I want to to is create a query with Criteria where I can get all the machines that contain a specific line.

I noticed Criteria has a Restrictions.in() but that checks whether a field of the table is in a Collection and I want to do it the other way around.

Thanks for helping me out,
Cheers,
Stef

Comment: Maybe revert your query: Query for the line, join in the Machines. Would that work?

Answer (score 0):

Following Hibernate documentation should help:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/manual/en-US/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-associations

Basically you'll need to create a 2nd criteria that refers to the elements of `lines` of the Machine class. i.e.

```
Criteria machineCriteria = session.createCriteria(Machine.class);
Criteria lineCriteria = machineCriteria.createCriteria("lines");
lineCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("fieldNameOfLineClass", valueOfFieldNameOfLineClass);
machineCriteria.list();
```

Answer (score 0):

I find this syntax more meaningful as well as more compact. Presuming that you have the id of a Line instance in your hand this would get you what you want.

```
    // we have a Long lineId
    Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Machine.class)
        .createAlias("lines", "line")
        .add(Restrictions.eq("line.id", lineId);
```